# for dentro de otro for

Tags: javascript, jquery, bucle-for

Quiero hacer algo como esto:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        let ii = i;

        for(var l = 'a'; l < 'z'; l++){
        let ll = l;

        }
}
```

Quiero que el for que esta dentro del otro for se ejecute de la ´a´ a la ´z´, 5 veces, pero solo imprime la a, me falta hacer algo mas?

Comment: Como saber que debe ir de la ´a´ a la ´z´, es un string lo que estas tratando de incrementar, deberías tener un array con el abecedario y así poder recorrerlo, ¿no?

Comment: porque `a` es menor `z` ? no entiendo? , el for que tienes dentro no tiene sentido?, porque estas haciendo que se comparen strings

Comment: Voto negativo por que el titulo no refleja el problema (usar un ciclo con textos)

Comment: El ciclo de adentro iteraba solo 1 vez, pero no sabia que lo de las letras era el problema, y como el problema principal era el numero de iteraciones de ciclo interno entonces puse ese titulo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes trabajar con simples caracteres. Tienes que convertirlos a su valor en [ASCII](https://ascii.cl/es/) para poder iterar sobre ellos.  Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {            
    for(var l = 'a'.charCodeAt(0); l < 'z'.charCodeAt(0); l++) {              
        console.log(String.fromCharCode(l));
    }
}
```

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias :)

Comment: que sentido tendrian los let en este codigo?

Comment: Ninguno, solo copie y pegue, pero ya edite.

Comment: deberias indicar adicionalmente que usas una variable diferente como indice (l en lugar de i)